# What does and does not belong in an ASP.NET MVC 2 Area folder?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

Visual Studio tooling will create "Models", "Views" and "Controllers" folders in any new ASP.NET MVC 2 Area.

[image: Areas Folder in Visual Studio]

What else should go into this folder?  Would you (for example) place custom ModelBinders in `Areas/MyReallyGreatArea/Binders` if they are only referenced in `MyReallyGreatArea`?

What is the best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, when I a custom `ModelBinder` in `MyReallyGreatArea` only I put it - as you suggested - into a folder within that area, e.g. `Areas/MyReallyGreatArea/Binder`s. When a `ModelBinder` is later used by a different area I then move it up into a folder named `Areas/Shared/Binders` or similar. That way I keep classes located close to where they are used. Why bother with the customer `ModelBinder` if `MyOtherEvenGreaterArea` doesn't use it?

The same applies for everything else. If it is used by `MyReallyGreatArea` only it will be located in there. If it is shared with a different area I put it into `Area/Shared` (and possibly properly named subfolders in there).

While this is likely to be only a minor issue if you work alone on this project or when then the project is still small, a well thought-through structures pays off as the project grows or as a larger team works on it. In some cases different areas are even worked on by different teams.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I like to keep the areas folder as lean as possible, however it depends on your project size. If you have a large 'web' project then you probably want to keep your models/binders and other plain objects in a seperate library for your business logic, alternatively if you only have a couple of areas and few other classes required then there I like the idea of keeping your area specific binders under the area folder.

I don't like shared plain classes floating around the 'web' project and beleive these should be in a seperate library, however your code may not be large enough to justify this.